# How can I handle multiple options for parameters in powershell?

Tags: parsing, powershell, parameters, arguments, powershell-2.0

I want to be able to have multiple forms of the same parameter like so:

```
param(
  [string]$p or $path = "C:\",
  [string]$f or $filter = "*.txt",
  [switch]$o or $overwrite
)
```

but I'm not sure how to do this. Most times, you would only be able to choose one (e.g. only $p or only $path). Is it possible to use multiple names for the same variable/parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
param(
  [Alias('p')]
  [string]$path = "C:\",
  [Alias('f')]
  [string]$filter = "*.txt",
  [Alias('o')]
  [switch]$overwrite
)
```

Note you can have multiple aliases too: `[Alias('p','thepath')]`

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell partial parameter name matching may be what your looking for.

```
# test.ps1
param($path)
write-host $path
```

Calling .\test.ps1 with either `.\test.ps1 -path "c:\windows"` or `.\test.ps1 -p "c:\windows"` will both match, and populate, the $path parameter.